# How do I add values from cetain nodes

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have the following structure in a source XML-file:

```
    <Measurements>
      <Measurement>
        <quantity>0.8</quantity>
        <unit>flm</unit>
      </Measurement>
      <Measurement>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <unit>pl</unit>
      </Measurement>
      <Measurement>
        <quantity>0</quantity>
        <unit>st</unit>
      </Measurement>
     </Measurements>
```

I've created a template for mapping these into the target XML in various target nodes, however I need to add a node in the target that includes a total of the value "quantity" in the "measurement" with element "unit" "st" and "pl"

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to sum "st" and "pl" together? Or separately?

Comment: I want to sum the <quantity> value together from the <Measurement> where the value in <unit> is either st or pl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum all `quantity` values of measurements whose units are either `st` or `pl`  you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/Measurements/Measurement[unit='st' or unit='pl']/quantity)"/>
```